What are the key configuration for Hyper-V client connection?
If the client and the Hyper-V 2019 server are connected to the same network and can communicate with each other, the client can access the Hyper-V server using Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). To establish a connection through the Hyper-V Manager on the client terminal, what are the necessary configurations that need to be set up?
I have two terminals, one still can't connect but the other one has been successful with connecting to the server through:
1. Configure WinRM on Client
```
winrm quickconfig
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="192.168.2.242"}'
```

2. Enable Credential Delegation through Group Policy

Open Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
Navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System ->
Credentials Delegation.
Modify Allow delegating fresh credentials and Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication. Add WSMAN/* and also the specific server IP.
Apply changes with: gpupdate /force

3. Manually Enable CredSSP on the Client
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "192.168.2.242"

While both terminal clients have been set up and have been configured in the same manner, why is the other terminal not able to connect, with the error "The computer "192.168.2.242" cannot be resolved..."? What are the key configurations for Hyper-V client connections that are missing?
